# Login using base64_encode(md5($Login.$Pass, true));

Tags: php, base64, md5

I'm having some troubles to make a login page. I'm still a beginner at PHP programming, but my login system works if it gets the right login and ID or the right login and email, but it doesnt work with the password.

That's how the password is encrypted on the registering page:

```
$Salt = base64_encode(md5($Login.$Pass, true));
```

That's a part of my login system:

```
$Login = StrToLower(Trim($_POST['login']));
$Password = Trim($_POST['passwd']);
$Password = "0x".md5($Login.$Password);
$sql = "select * from users where name ='".$Login."' and  passwd ='".$Password."' ";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please include the authentication verification code. Thank you

Comment: <?php
include("configpw.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
session_start();
$Login = StrToLower(Trim($_POST['login']));
$Password = Trim($_POST['passwd']);
$Password = "0x".md5($Login.$Password);
$sql = ("select * from users where name ='".$Login."' and  passwd ='".$Password."' ");
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
{    
     while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {    
                   $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'];
            header("Location: user.php");
       }
}
else
{
    header("Location: fail.php");
}
}
?>

Comment: I'm not sure about what you've meant, but that's the whole script :p

Comment: Yes, this is what I was asking. Can you, also, share the code that insert (create) the user,?

Comment: As you are are encrypting the password($Salt = base64_encode(md5($Login.$Pass, true));) on registration page, you also have to encrypt it while you are making login . Please try this if this didn't work, then please share your registration page code.

Comment: MySQL_Query("call adduser('$Login', '$Salt', '0', '0', '0', '0', '$Email', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '$Salt')") or die ("Tables were not added");

Comment: Show us the code where you INSERT new  or update password

Comment: INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `name`, `passwd`, `Prompt`, `answer`, `truename`, `idnumber`, `email`, `mobilenumber`, `province`, `city`, `phonenumber`, `address`, `postalcode`, `gender`, `birthday`, `creatime`, `qq`, `passwd2`) VALUES
(16, 'testing', 'gj54X6MyHIxV4PNoFfr0xA==', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'myemail@gmail.com', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2015-02-08 16:32:35', '', 'gj54X6MyHIxV4PNoFfr0xA=='),

Comment: That's the login page: http://pastebin.com/UZkvRr46

Answer (score 2):

Before investing any additional effort in your login code, I would instead highly suggest spending your time researching the topics of SQL injection and PHP's parameterized query features.  As posted, your code is a textbook example of login code that is trivial to hack with SQL injection.

Currently, it appears to me that simply entering the following in the "name" login field would allow me to login every time:

```
' or True;
```

I apologize that this is not a direct answer to your question but I do not yet have the reputation points to use comments.  We all must start learning somewhere but coding a login feature is not to be taken on early in your PHP learning process.  Even after years of experience, many people will still advise to never roll your own authentication and instead use an existing framework (good advice in my opinion).

Comment: It's fine. Any new knowledge is welcome, I'm just trying to make an user panel for the game I'm developing and I'm worried, that's why I wanted to do this panel, but thanks for the advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you stored the password you encrypted it like:

```
base64_encode(md5($Login.$Pass, true))
```

and when you check the password you are saying that your password is encrypted like:

```
"0x".md5($Login.$Password);
```

As an example:
I am using user = 'user' and password = 'password'

You are storing the password like `1ECu0YmhP/lw2sfn6PmHsg==` and when you check the password, this is `0xd5745f9425eceb269f9fe01d0bef06ff`

Testing Code:

```
$ php -a
php > echo base64_encode(md5('user'.'password', true));
1ECu0YmhP/lw2sfn6PmHsg==

php > echo "0x".md5('login'.'password');
0xd5745f9425eceb269f9fe01d0bef06ffphp >
```

Suggestions:

1. You should sanitize your variables **Read**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
2. mysql is depricated, please start using `msqli` or `PDO` (recommended) **Read**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
3. For a better and more secure password encryption please use `password_hash` **Read**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php & http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: I got it. So I need to decode base64?

Comment: yes, and add or remove "0x". Both encryptions should look the same.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you got the Lea Tano answer.

You don't need to decode base64.

You need encode it!!! 
:-) so change your code to something like this:

```
$Login = StrToLower(Trim($_POST['login']));
$Password = Trim($_POST['passwd']);
$Password = base64_encode(md5($Login.$Password, true));
$sql = "select * from users where name ='".$Login."' and  passwd ='".$Password."' ";
```